# Make data in a particular col as link in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagrid view that gets the data from oracle database using this code.

```
        Dim UpperCase As String = UCase(Instance_NameTextBox.Text)
        Dim sql As String = "select instance_name,application_url from INSTANCE_DETAILS where upper(INSTANCE_NAME) like '%" + UpperCase + "%'"
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn)
        da.Fill(ds, "TEST")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

I need the second column of the view to come as link that opens the url in browser.Any help?

Comment: You can convert that column to templatecolumn and than place a hyperlink in that with data binding to field.

Comment: @hemal Can you give me an example on how to do that.I'm new to vb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using the following code.

```
        Dim col As New DataGridViewLinkColumn
        Dim sql As String = "select * from INSTANCE_DETAILS where upper(INSTANCE_NAME) like '%" + UpperCase + "%'"
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn)
        da.Fill(ds, "TEST")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        Dim obj As New DataGridViewRow
        Dim Data As String
```

Follwing is to change it for each row which takes the data from the 3rd col.

```
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0

        Dim x As Integer
        x = DataGridView1.RowCount
        For Each obj In DataGridView1.Rows
            If i < x - 1 Then
                Data = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(3).ToString()
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Links").Value = Data
                i = i + 1
            End If

        Next obj
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a TemplateColumn

```
   TemplateField myTemplate = new TemplateField();
   myTemplate.HeaderText = "MyLinkButton";
   MainGridView.Columns.Add(myTemplate);
   GridView.DataSource = GetData(); \\Your data source here
   GridView.DataBind();
```

Then In your GridView RowDataBound event

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
       HyperLink myLink = new HyperLink ();
       myLink.ID = "HyperLink1";
       myLink.Text = "Click here";
       myLink.NavigateUrl = e.Row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
       e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(myLink);
   }
}
```

Comment: But i need to fetch the url value from the database itself as it varies for each row.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You basically traverse through each databound row, get the cell value you need, and then update it with hyperlink